# How can you check whether a site is hosted by Google Sites or not?

Tags: command-line, google

I suppose there may be a one-line Linux command to check that.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to check though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you can specifically identify what you're looking for, and I'm not entirely sure what you mean since Google Apps is a suite of stuff. Sites are hosted by other products that form a part of Google Apps. I'm assuming that you mean to refer to Google Sites.

The function below actually looks for sites that contain `GSE` in their server name in the HTTP headers. Cursory tests indicate that this will identify Google Sites, but those tests are incomplete.

Define this function somewhere. You can type it directly into Bash, or put it into one of your shell startup files:

```
function hosted_by_google_sites {
  if [[ "$(curl --head --silent "$1" | egrep '^Server:')" =~ GSE ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
if hosted_by_google_sites "http://www.example.com/some_url"; then
  do_something
fi
```

Or:

```
hosted_by_google_sites "http://www.example.com/some_url" && echo "Yes. Hosted by Google sites."
```

You said you wanted a one-liner. I'll leave that as an exercise for you, since representing this as a function is far superior, IMO. It could be done as a one-liner, but it'd be messy.

Comment: That's right, it was Google Sites. That's exactly it, no need for one-liner. Thank you.